# Perfect Regex for url

Tags: java

I want to validate all type of url but few of my conditions are not working with the following regex:

```
^((https?|ftp|smtp|http):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*\.(com|in)$
```

It is not working with

1. http://google.com
2. https://google.com
3. google.com

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your regex, you'll see that you require two dots (I added white spaces to identify them) in your url:

```
^((https?|ftp|smtp|http):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+   \.   [a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*   \.   (com|in)$
```

I recommend you to use https://regex101.com/ to check your regex.

But like [George](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505350/perfect-regex-for-url#comment99598491_56505350) says, you can use commons regex for that purpose, instead of making a new one.

---

By the way, `https?` is catching `https` and `http` so that `(https?|...|http)`=`(https?|...)`

Comment: But if i will remove the first dot then it will say valid url for the condition below-www.com

Comment: But `below-www.com` is a valid url, just like by google.com, you don't need to have an extra dot.